# Force closed after first activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a few problems with my first app..

Later on there is the error log, the SplashActivity (my test-intro) and the FullscreenActivity, which I would starting with `intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, FullscreenActivity.class);` but I receive a FC and the big error log. I shortened it a bit, if the full log is needed, i can post it in comment or update the Thread!

Hopefully you can help me, i searched for hours but didn't find a solution..

kindly regards

svansolo

**Log:**

```
03/01 03:36:19: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal/engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal.test | engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal
Connecting to engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal
W/ActivityThread: Application engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8605', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1466)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal-1/lib/arm
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
               java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5860)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5452)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/data/engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.0.0_da4b7ee275c24adb76e999a72b3b1d1271afc7ad-classes.dex)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751) 
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726) 
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5860) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5452) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5391) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
D/FA: Debug logging enabled
D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 165856110
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal, 1:998250257852:android:fddd73d655be689d
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                           MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                           EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
                           bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
                           MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
                           FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
                           cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
                           LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
                           dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
                           sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
                           URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
                           qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
                           gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
                           VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
                           A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
                           4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
                           zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
                           yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
                           KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
                           Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
                           MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 55018254
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 55018292
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/data/engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.0.0_da4b7ee275c24adb76e999a72b3b1d1271afc7ad-classes.dex): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
D/FA: Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=14376}]
E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/data/engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.0.0_da4b7ee275c24adb76e999a72b3b1d1271afc7ad-classes.dex): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
V/FA: onActivityCreated
D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/lib/arm:/system/fake-libs:/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a for namespace 0xb6d5b090
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/lib/arm:/system/fake-libs:/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a for namespace 0xb6d5b0d0
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/n/armeabi-v7a
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/n/armeabi
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=28KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=27KB, data=27KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal, PID: 16317
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal/engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:25)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8605', transport: 'socket'
```

**SplashActivity:** ("Mainactivity")

```
package engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, FullscreenActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

**FullscreenActivity:** --

```
package engelsschmidt.runtheropefinal;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private View mControlsView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        mVisible = true;
         mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        Button button_new_game = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_new_game);
        Button button_highscore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_highscore);
        button_new_game.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_highscore.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            //if (actionBar != null) {
             //   actionBar.show();
            //}
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //if (actionBar != null) {
        //    actionBar.hide();
        //}
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_new_game:
                Intent fullscreenSecondActivity = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, FullscreenSecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(fullscreenSecondActivity);
                this.finish();
                break;
            case R.id.button_highscore:
                Intent fullscreenThirthActivity = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, FullscreenThirthActivity.class);
                startActivity(fullscreenThirthActivity);
                this.finish();
                break;
            //case R.id.button_charakter:
        }

    }

    public void highscore(View view) {
    }

    public void new_game(View view) {
    }

    public void charakter(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `mContentView.setOnClickListener` what do you expect that to do?

Comment: Good question, it's inizialist by AS.. It's my first try with AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mContentView` is null.

Before the onclick function. You need to define the `mContentView` to whatever layout you're using.

For example

```
mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.thisisidoflayout);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast help!
One of the problems is solved, did you have any idea about the 
"Firebase Api initialization failure."
And
"E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: [...]" 
? :)

Comment: Same thing. Just like sir Caspain said, problem is initialization. Try to read in firebase. Once you get it. It will be easy to you.

Answer (score 0):

One of your view in FullScreenActivity is null.

```
 mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
        }
    });
```

mContentView was never initialized.

Comment: mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mContentViewID);